# Trouble reading row of doubles from file C++

Tags: c++, file, matrix, iostream

for some reason the code below stores a bunch of 0s into my doubles array and it doesn't write the 0s into the file im trying to create. This is my first time programming in c++ so I'm still getting used to some of the basic things. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

double* getMatrix(int m, int n, char const*  fileName) {
    ifstream inFile(fileName);
    if(!inFile.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to open file");
    }
    double* newMatrix = new double[m*n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m * n; ++i) {
        inFile >> newMatrix[i];
    }
    inFile.close();
    return newMatrix;
}

void writeMatrix(int n, int m, double* matrix, char const* fileName) {
    ofstream out(fileName);
    for(int i=0; i < m*n && out; ++i) {
        out << matrix[i] << "\n";
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double* newMatrix = getMatrix(3, 4, "matrixA.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        cout << newMatrix[i] << endl;
    }
    writeMatrix(3, 4, newMatrix, "matrixC.txt");
    delete newMatrix;
}
```

and here is the file I'm trying to read in

```
   0.314723686393179
   0.405791937075619
  -0.373013183706494
   0.413375856139019
   0.132359246225410
  -0.402459595000590
  -0.221501781132952
   0.046881519204984
   0.457506835434298
   0.464888535199277
  -0.342386918322452
   0.470592781760616
```

edit: updated getMatrix function to what is below and now I'm getting wrong values in output and still unable to create the file "matrixC.txt"

```
double* getMatrix(int m, int n, char* const fileName) {
    ifstream inFile(fileName);
    double* newMatrix = new double[m*n];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < m * n; ++i) {
            inFile >> newMatrix[i];
        }
    } catch (ifstream::failure e) {
        cout << "exception opening file";
    }

    inFile.close();
    return newMatrix;
}
```

and here is what I am getting as output

```
-1.28823e-231
-1.28823e-231
6.95324e-310
6.95327e-310
6.95324e-310
6.95327e-310
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

edit2: updated the main code block with newer code that handles if the file is not open. Still doesn't

edit3:
I solved the problem, I added this line set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY"~/ClionProjects/MatMult") to my CMakeLists.txt file

Comment: Replace the input with a stringstream to further reduce the code to a minimal example. Consider using `std::vector` in the future, too. Lastly, you are not actually handling the case that the input file could not be opened, I guess that's the fault. Just `throw std::runtime_error("failed to open file");` if that happens. BTW: Closing the stream before returning is unnecessary, and you omit that anyway on other exit paths of the function.

Comment: For this I can't use vectors even though I know it's good style. Also, I don't understand where I am supposed to put that throw statement since I don't know c++ exception handling. Sorry for making you spoon feed this to me.

Comment: Unrelated: Also, your filename parameter types are wrong. There is a fundamental difference between what you have, `char * const`, and what you should have, `char const *` (or `const char *`). The former is a non-mutable pointer to mutable data; the latter is a mutable pointer to non-mutable data. Your compiler should have warned you about this. If it did not, jam up your warning levels.

Comment: You can use `throw ...;` like you would use `return ...;`. Just check if opening succeeded and then handle the case if not. Similarly check if input actually succeeded. Try this in a separate file, so you can better concentrate on just this one issue.

Comment: Concerning your edit, I never wrote that you should catch the exception but that you should throw one when opening the input file fails. Don't bother yourself with catching it now, that comes later.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked OK for me - as @UlrichEckhardt said, this points to not being able to open the file. test `if (!inFile)` after `inFile` is opened to see if this is the case.

Comment: So I added a condition to check if the file is open after i try to open it and it seems that the exception you told me to add gets thrown so I guess I'm not even able to open the file even though it's in the same directory as my source code.

Comment: The output file you create will be in the right directory, so if the input file is in the same directory as the output file, that isn't it. Could it be a case-sensitive problem, or possibly you have the input file open (and locked) in an editor?

Comment: @vicg how are you *starting* this process, and what toolchain are you using? Most IDE's require you specify the working directory and have a default specification if you don't. Ex: MS Visual Studio's default working directory on launch is the folder containing the *project file* (the .vcprojx file), which is not always what people think.

Comment: @WhozCraig I figured, im using CLion with CMake. Tried just compiling from the command line but I got a massive error

Comment: I solved the problem, I added this line

    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY"~/ClionProjects/MatMult") 

to my CMakeLists.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to compile and run your code and after a quick fixing of include directives it compiled just fine and I could not reproduce your error.

Here's the code I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

double* getMatrix(int m, int n, char const*  fileName) {
    ifstream inFile(fileName);
    if(!inFile.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to open file");
    }
    double* newMatrix = new double[m*n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m * n; ++i) {
        inFile >> newMatrix[i];
    }
    inFile.close();
    return newMatrix;
}

void writeMatrix(int n, int m, double* matrix, char const* fileName) {
    ofstream out(fileName);
    for(int i=0; i < m*n && out; ++i) {
        out << matrix[i] << "\n";
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double* newMatrix = getMatrix(3, 4, "matrixA.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        cout << newMatrix[i] << endl;
    }
    writeMatrix(3, 4, newMatrix, "matrixC.txt");
    delete newMatrix;
}
```

Here's how I built and ran:

```
$ g++ test.cc && ./a.out > test.txt
$ diff test.txt matrixC.txt
$ cat matrixC.txt 
0.314724
0.405792
-0.373013
0.413376
0.132359
-0.40246
-0.221502
0.0468815
0.457507
0.464889
-0.342387
0.470593
```

Isn't this how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, the problem was actually with my CMake.txt file. This is what happens when you go into something without knowing your toolchain. Thanks for the help